# C - subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Tags: c, arrays

I declared an array and pass a 2D array as a parameter. However I keep getting the same error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector. 
for this line: vertex[i][j-1] = shape[i][j];

How can I solve it?

header file:

```
GLfloat mijnplayer [][4] ={
{0,-0.091057,0.198079,0.084590},
{0,-0.158043,0.158043,0.071039},
{0,-0.071039,0.158043,0.158043}};
```

function call:

```
int main(void)
{   

drawVertex(mijnplayer,3,1);

}

void drawVertex(GLfloat shape[][4], int numberVertex, int shape)
{
    int i,j;
    GLfloat vertex[][3]={0};


    //convert 4element array to 3 element array
    for(i=0;i<numberVertex;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<4;j++)
        {
            vertex[i][j-1] = shape[i][j];
        }

    }

    for(i=0;i<numberVertex;i++)
    {

        glVertex3fv(vertex[i]);
    }

}
```

EDIT:

the complete compiler output:

cc    -c -o mijnTest.o mijnTest.c

mijnTest.c:23:59: error: conflicting types for ‘shape’

void drawVertex(GLfloat shape[][4], int numberVertex, int shape)
                                                           ^

mijnTest.c:23:25: note: previous definition of ‘shape’ was here

void drawVertex(GLfloat shape[][4], int numberVertex, int shape)
                         ^

mijnTest.c: In function ‘drawVertex’:

mijnTest.c:43:26: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor 
vector

vertex[i][j-1] = shape[i][j];
                          ^

mijnTest.c: In function ‘drawScene’:

mijnTest.c:69:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘drawVertex’ from 
incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

drawVertex(assen,6,0);
  ^

mijnTest.c:23:6: note: expected ‘GLfloat (*)[4]’ but argument is of type 
‘GLfloat (*)[3]’

void drawVertex(GLfloat shape[][4], int numberVertex, int shape)
      ^

make: *** [mijnTest.o] Error 1

Comment: The data type of shape is int.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include the *complete* output from the compiler, in full and unedited, and including any possible informational notes and warnings.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, added.

Comment: When reading error messages, always start at the *top*. In your case you have `mijnTest.c:23:59: error: conflicting types for ‘shape’`. That should lead you to take a close look at the function declaration and its arguments.

Comment: to start, there are two different parameters to the function: `drawVertex()` that are both named `shape'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `shape` is an variable of data type `int` and **its  neither array nor pointer nor vector.**

Either you got the data type wrong or you are just using the wrong variable.

Comment: nothing of what you mentionned I think. The complete code: http://dpaste.com/3RN0KR6

Comment: @J.Doe How can you write shape[i][j] and at the same time write int shape.

Comment: OMG! didn t see that, had been searching for soo long!

Answer (score 1):

A declaration like

```
GLfloat vertex[][3]
```

is only valid as a function argument (and then it's equal to `GLfloat (*vertex)[3]`). If you declare an array as a local or global variable, you *must* give it a size.

It works when you define `mijnplayer` because then the compiler can deduce the size from the data you use for initialization (the size is set implicitly). If you don't do it then the compiler can't know what size the array is, and you need to specify it explicitly.